# Updating a document in mongoDB embedded in other collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I am still new to the concept of non-relational databases.I am using MongoDb with atlas in a node application.My collections have a lot of embedded documents, for example this mongoose schema

```
 const feedbackSchema = new Schema({
  member: {
    type: userSchema,
    required: true
  },
  datePosted: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
  },
  feedbackText: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
const UserSchema = new Schema(
  {
    type: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    userData: {}
  },
  { strict: false }
);
```

member (type userSchema) is another collection.So my question is if a member in the member collection is updated,do I have to manually update this member in the feedback collection?

Comment: You should show the userSchema but, I think that you are using it in the wrong way

Comment: ok, here it is .